# PHP date - return time from back on date diff

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have created a function to display difference between two dates: actual and from a database.

I have the following code:

```
$date_a = new DateTime( 'now' );
$date_b = new DateTime( $Time );

$interval = date_diff( $date_b, $date_a );

if ( $interval->format( '%m' ) >= 1 ) {
    return 'Dodano: ' . $interval->format( '%m' ) . ' miesięcy temu';
} elseif ( $interval->format( '%d' ) >= 1 ) {
    return 'Dodano: ' . $interval->format( '%d' ) . ' dni temu';
} elseif ( $interval->format( '%h' ) >= 1 ) {
    return 'Dodano: ' . $interval->format( '%h' ) . ' godz. temu';
} elseif ( $interval->format( '%i' ) >= 1 ) {
    return 'Dodano: ' . $interval->format( '%i' ) . ' min. temu';
} elseif ( $interval->format( '%s' ) >= 1 ) {
    return 'Dodano: ' . $interval->format( '%s' ) . ' sekund temu';
}
```

Months, days, hours and minutes are ok, but on seconds displays:

```
Dodano: 59 min. temu
```

Not

```
Dodano: n sekund temu
```

Why?

Comment: Can you create a php fiddle? http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: I just tried it out on my server and was confused cause I had the same error. See the problem is your server time is different to what you think it is. It is most likely an hour early (var_dump $date_a and you will see)

Comment: Ok, this is bad time on my server (-1 hour), thanks

Comment: Could you accept my answer below? Means this question will no longer receive unnecessary attention. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $date_a is an hour early due to your server time not being what you think it is.

I was confused too when I tried it out on my server, but after var_dump-ing $date_a, it was clear that was the issue.

Hopefully that was able to solve it for you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call DateInterval::format() to display that difference as a string.
Add the following line to your code.
$interval->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');